# I need to run a test for my spring batch that reads from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, junit, spring-batch

I am new to testing. I have a completed Spring Batch job using mongodb and gradle. I need some help getting started with either a junit  test or integration test to ensure my project is working correctly. I have searched through Stack and did not find anything that can help me understand what I am doing. A lot of the codes online does not pertain to my spring batch. Could someone help guide me to fully understand what I need to do to get started or point me in  the right direction.

Thank you

here is a code i found, does not work, is there another way I can make this run?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com." })


public class BatchTest {

@Autowired
private PaymentPortalRepository repository;
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
@Test
public void testSaveAndFindRxBusiness() throws Exception {
    PaymentAudit paymentAudit = new PaymentAudit(null, "1", false, 
"RETAIL", null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, null);
    repository.save(paymentAudit);
    PaymentAudit paymentAudit2 = new PaymentAudit(null, "2", false, 
"RETAIL", null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
 null, 
 null, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, null);
    repository.save(paymentAudit2);
    assertEquals(paymentAudit, repository.findByRxBusiness("1"));
    assertEquals(paymentAudit2, repository.findByRxBusiness("2"));
    assertNull(repository.findByRxBusiness("3"));
   }
}
```

ERROR:

```
14:53:20.862 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@60db1c0e] to prepare test instance [com..ecom.BatchTest@e25951c]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com..ecom.BatchTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com..ecom.spring_batchjob.repository.PaymentPortalRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at 

    org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ecom.spring_batchjob.repository.PaymentPortalRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
    14:53:20.871 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@81d9a72 testClass = BatchTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@747f281 testClass = BatchTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@10feca44, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1e683a3e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@14555e0a, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
    14:53:20.874 [Thread-0] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4f4c4b1a: startup date [Tue Jan 08 14:53:20 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
    14:53:20.874 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
    14:53:20.876 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1ab06251: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor$SpyPostProcessor,org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.Moc

kitoPostProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are autowiring a bean of type `PaymentPortalRepository` in your test class but no beans of this type are found in your test context. Hence the error.

The problem is that your test class does not load any Spring application context. You need to add `@ContextConfiguration` and specify which Spring application context you want to load for this test (use the `classes` attribute if you use Java configuration and `locations` attribute if you use XML configuration). This application context should contain a bean of type `PaymentPortalRepository` and other beans used in your test.

Moreover, the `@Configuration` annotation means the annotated class is a source of bean definitions. This is not the case in your test so you can remove it.

You can find examples of how to test Spring Batch jobs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting

Comment: Thank you for you response. I followed the link you sent me and tried using the end to end example. Since I am not using  JDBC, I was wondering how could I use this with mongodb as my datasource? i tried adding mongotemplate and using that to try and update but it is not working for me. Any advice?